Excel VBA: IMEX=1 doesn't work as expected to treat all the records as text
I have a pretty large source Excel file where its first column Code has a lot of numeric data with a minority of cells with text.
My issue is that IMEX=1 setting in the connection doesn't work as expected, and I still found that all the few text cells are nullified when stored in rst as the major datatype is numeric.
So, what am I missing here to make all the records in the column Code be treated as text when stored in rst regardless of the dominant numeric datatype?
P.S. The first thirteen records contain pure numeric data, so this might be the issue as pointed out by @Rory.
Sub RetrieveDataUsingADO()
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strConnect As String
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset

    strFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "/Data.xlsx"

    strConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=""" & strFile & _
                """;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";"
    
    cnn.Open ConnectionString:=strConnect
    
    strSQL = "SELECT [Code] FROM [Payments$]"

    rst.Open strSQL, cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockReadOnly

    Do Until rst.EOF
        Debug.Print CStr(rst.Fields("Code").Value)
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop

    rst.Close
    cnn.Close
End Sub


Why do  you think that IMEX=1 is the problem? Please, try the next connection string: "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & strFile & "';" & "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"";". Firstly, you do not need provider between double quotes and if there are spaces in strFile, you need to place it between quotes (')...

@FaneDuru still your proposed connection string doesn't solve the issue of nullifying, for example, the 14th record 16Q1234 after 13 pure numeric records in the column Code of the source file, which makes this line Debug.Print CStr(rst.Fields("Code").Value) fail after successful prints of the first thirteen numeric records.

IMEX=1 only works if the driver detects the column type as mixed, which is based on the rows it scans (8 by default I think). Unless you have text values in those rows, that setting will have no effect at all.

@Rory In my case, the first 13 rows contain pure numeric data. So, how can I fix this?

Do you have to use ADO? If so, do you have control over the source file?

By following the instructions here Using the TypeGuessRows setting for Excel Driver, and editing the value of TypeGuessRows to 0 or any desired big number solved the issue.

In my case, I went to Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\REGISTRY\MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Access Connectivity Engine\Engines\Excel to change its value.
